# Does Flutter support cascading styles?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to be able to set a default text style which I can use across my app and then overwrite part of that style in specific circumstances. React Native supports this, does Flutter support it too please? Or if not, how can I achieve something like this?

Example of how I'd hope this would work:

`style.dart:`

```
ThemeData appTheme() {
   return ThemeData(
      ...
      textTheme: TextTheme(
         headline1: TextStyle(fontSize: 26.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
         ...
      )
   )
}
```

`body.dart:`

```
Text('My text here', style: [TextStyle(color: myColorVariable), themeData.textTheme.headline1])
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

`Theme.of(context).textTheme.copyWith()`

or even

`Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1.copyWith()`

to change the default for a specific text widget.